# package not found error in building pom in maven

Tags: java, maven-2

i am trying to compile a pom file for a project (say `com.mycompany.package2`). Now some of the files have import statements like `import com.mycompany.package1.someClass` .So i made a pom file for files in `com.mycompany.package1` and added this pom as a parent to  pom made for `com.mycompany.package2` . However, on executing mvn compile for this new pom (`com.mycompany.package2`) i get error that the package `com.mycompany.package1` does not exist. 
I can't understand why am i getting this error and how to correct it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would advice you to go your .m2 folder which is your local maven repository folder (or where-ever you have your maven repository) to check if you can find package1.jar/war 
if you dont find it, then you can be sure - you have not compiled your package1 in the first place, in which case you should do a **maven compile(mvn install) to your project1 first before you do it to your project2**

**EDIT**
if project2 has import of project1, then project1 is a dependency to project2
 in which case you need to add project1.jar as a dependency in your project2 pom file... like this

```
<dependency> <groupId>package1</groupId> <artifactId>com.mycompany.package1</artifactId> <version>1.0.0</version> </dependency>
```

Comment: thanks..i had done that by compiling the parent as a jar..but then i got error that parent should be packaged as pom and not jar..so i re-installed it as a pom

Comment: ok..so it means i need to add it as a dependencny and not  parent?

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked like this way, I added all my packages under src/test and after that this issue was resolved

Comment: Your answer must contain an example in code ...
After all, this question is old ...